# Long division symbol (HTML and/or CSS)

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a way to display the traditional long division symbol using HTML/CSS (kinda like what's shown here: http://barronstestprep.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/longdiv1.png).

This (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/27cc/index.htm) is basically what I need, but I don't think many people would have the proper font installed on their computer to see it (I don't, at least).

I've also tried this (below), but it doesn't display consistently on Chrome and FF...

```
4<span style="text-decoration: overline;"><span style="font-size: 14px">)</span>84</span>
```

This should be displaying 84 ÷ 4 with the long division box.

Ideas?

Comment: I don't see your unicode....on the website, it gave a Unicode symbol to put in, and you should see it.

Comment: Can you not just use an image for the long division sign if there is not HTML code for the symbol, you will not have the problem of users not have the correct font installed then.

Comment: I'll be generating random numbers to go under the div. box.  So, an image wouldn't work.

Comment: You can use absolute positioning for the image so that the text will still go directly beneath the symbol

Comment: Using an image will cause issues for random length values used as dividends. What if the dividend were to be, say, 8 digits in length at some point but only 3 digits long at other times? I am certain the OP wants the Vinculum (the line above the dividend and below the quotient) to be only be long enough to stretch as far as the dividend does; i.e. variably generated. My first thought was to pretty much generate one using a javascript function that uses the Parenthesis in a larger font size to the numbers used then variably draw a line with length calculated using the width of the dividend.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<span style="border-right: 1px black solid; border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 0px">
    4 
</span>
<span style="border-top: 1px black solid; ">
    84 
</span>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7KauJ/)

Comment: Just what I was making in the fiddle :)

Comment: Just wondering... Why do you have the `class="numbers"` if you don't style the class?

Comment: When CSS is disabled, the content appears as “4 84”, so the approach is not robust as such. For example, a screen reader will just read the numbers, with no indication of any division.

Comment: This question marked as `css`, so why one would disable it? O_O

Comment: @grmmph, marking the question as css does not change the reality: the approach, in addition to being tricky and producing a typographically inferior presentation, is not robust and accessible – for example, someone using a screen reader has really no notion of “disabling” or “enabling” CSS (the reader may apply some of CSS, but surely not borders).

Comment: Everything you said is correct. If there is a way to use long-division symbol to be shown in ALL screens and devices, please submit your answer. If we will start to disqualify solutions just because they cannot be shown on some certain devices, you'll have to avoid all HTML5 framework. That's why we have fallbacks.

Comment: @grmmph, the point is that this approach has no fallback in it.

Comment: This breaks accessibility. Don't do this!

Comment: this seems to be the simplest method to pretty much draw the symbol, although I am not a fan of the perpendicular 90deg angle at the left intersection of the Vinculum that is created using your method of the border-right. Instead, I modified the usage to use the closed parenthesis and styled it to be 135% font-size, and put it inside the span for border-top (the vinculum). adding hard spaces after the divisor and before the quotient made it look very neat, and works well with different base font-sizes. Advice to other users: be sure to use universally available fonts for this.

Answer (score 1):

The concept and notation of “long division” is traditional, in some traditions, of teaching arithmetic at school, and it is used in contexts where the steps of integer division are explained graphically. There is no reliable way to do this in HTML and CSS except by using images, either large images containing an entire long division as a process or piecewise, e.g. one piece containing just a number, the long division operator, and another number (as in the jpg referred to in the question). This is how e.g. http://www.mathsisfun.com/long_division.html does this. The page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division uses preformatted text, construction symbols from Ascii characters like “)” and “_”, but the result is primitive-looking and is not robust (e.g., turns to gibberish in a screen reader).

When using an image, you should write an `alt` text that expresses the idea verbally. This somewhat depends on context, but I’m afraid it would need to be longish, like `alt="long division with divisor 4, dividend 84"`.

Using just HTML and CSS to construct long divisions is rather hopeless, since HTML and CSS are rather powerless with anything involving essential two-dimensionality in math notations (i.e., mathematical expressions that are not simple linear sequences of characters). Even constructing a [square root expression](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/math/#uol), with a vinculum extending over the radicand, requires trickery that easily fails, more or less, and showing such an expression is similar to, but essentially simpler than a long division expression.

The character U+27CC LONG DIVISION would theoretically let you write a long division expression, even in plain text, since it is defined in the Unicode standard so that it “graphically extends over the dividend”. This is however largely theoretical, for several reasons. In addition to limited font coverage (which could be dealt with using a downloadable font with `@font-face`), the approach suffers from lack of software support. The idea “graphically extends over the dividend” is not easily implemented. While browsers may (when using a suitable font) render 84⟌4 properly, they fail with 84⟌42 (the symbol extends over the “4” after it but not over the “2”). The reason seems to be that in fonts that contain U+27CC, it might be implemented with advance rules that imply that operator seems to extend over the next *digit*, but to make it extend over the next *number* (digit sequence), software support above the simple font level would be needed.

Comment: Actually Jukka, I think I could write an AAT mif to get U+27CC to behave correctly with up to 8 following digits. I'll try at the weekend.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML5, you can directly use **MathML**. MathML 3 supports the `<mlongdiv>` element:

```
<figure>
  <math>
    <mlongdiv>
      <mn>4</mn>
      <mn></mn>
      <mn>84</mn>
    </mlongdiv>
  </math>
  <figcaption>
    This will display as a long division in browsers that support MathML 3.
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

For MathML 2 you can use a Javascript solution based on LaTeX, such as [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/). Here is a [long division example](http://html5mathml.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/longdiv-mj-mml2.html) which uses the MathJax TeX parser to parse input of the form `\longdiv{84}{4}`.

Comment: Yeah, I may use Mathjax at some point, but the accepted answer above is better for my purposes.  Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: MathJax unfortunately does not yet support `mlongdiv`, but in fairness, neither does any browser (except old IE versions via the MathPlayer plugin).

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Yeah, I was kind of implying that (that MathML 3 will be coming soon to HTML5 browsers, but MathML 2 via MathJax will have to do till then)

Comment: MathJax already supports most of MathML 3, just not yet elementary math. Also, browser support for MathML is not moving forward at all right now.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Ahh, that's good news! I had read that it did not, and haven't tried to use MathML 3 with it myself.